# Get startTime element value in an array

Tags: reactjs, datetime, console.log

May I know how to get the startTime value in the array? I use this code `{props.StartTime}` it doesn't work. I want to get the StartTime result is `Thu Dec 22 2022 21:20:00 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)`

[image: img1]

This is my original code what I do, only {props.StartTime} is doesn't work:

```html
const contentTemplate = props => {
    return (
      <div className="template-wrap">
        <div class="e-date-time">
          <div class="e-date-time-icon e-icons"></div>
          <div class="e-date-time-wrapper e-text-ellipsis">
            <div class="e-date-time-details e-text-ellipsis">
              {props.StartTime}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="e-location">
          <div class="e-location-icon e-icons"></div>
          <div class="e-location-details e-text-ellipsis">{props.Location}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="e-resource">
          <div class="e-resource-icon e-icons"></div>
          <div class="e-resource-details e-text-ellipsis">
            {props.DoctorList}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: *doesn't work* is not helpful at all. Do you get any errors? What does `props.StartTime` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that these might be `Date` objects so perhaps try `toString()`:

```
{props.StartTime.toString()}
```

For formatted output to match the locale perhaps reference [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#instance_methods) list of `Date` to string methods.